# magento homepage not working correctly

Tags: magento

I want to customize my homepage but my homepage always shows the last product which added to site! I defined home page to be a CMS page in configuration section but it's not working.

when I go to the URL of that page (localhost/magento/home) it shows the right content but when I go to my sit URL (currently localhost/magneto) it shows latest product!

Comment: Are you doing any changes to your homepage via xml?

Answer (score 1):

Goto **System=>Configuration=>Web=>Default Pages**
**Default Web Url** to **cms**
**CMS Home Page** ==> **Select your homepage title from the dropdown**

Comment: i think the issue is because URL rewrite managment, goto Catalog->URL Rewrite Management and check the target path  localhost/magneto was rewrited.

Comment: I checked that, there wasn't any field in there

Comment: can you send me the screenshot for the homepage which you are getting now ?